# Can I export specific metrics from one GCP Project to another?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a shared GKE cluster on project X, and I would like to have access to metrics related to namespace `my_namespace` in project Y.

I use Managed Prometheus for GKE to collect the metrics, and all that works great, but of course all the metrics are within project X, and project Y doesn't have access to them.

I understand that I can set up project X as a scoping project, however the issue is that then all metrics are visible to project Y, and I don't want that.

I would like to only expose metrics from the specific namespace to the other GCP Project. Is it possible to set this up either via scoping or via Managed Prometheus?

Comment: Refer to [Enable namespace-restricted access to cluster resources](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/restrict-resources-access-by-namespace), Which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy That seems to only relate to cluster resources, not metrics. Namespace-restricted access is already set up on the cluster

Comment: Hello @Illidanek, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.  If not, please do not hesitate to create a new feature request [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) thread describing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn’t a direct way of doing this, I have a theory that could work in your case by creating a `custom metrics descriptor` in project A and exporting the custom metrics to project B with a metric export. Here would be the steps to do so:

1. Create a custom metric descriptor in project A with the metrics you want to expose to project B (which in this case are the metrics from the specific GKE namespace). You can use the following official GCP documents to do so [User-defined metrics overview](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics) & [Create user-defined metrics with the API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics).
2. Create a metrics export in project A using the custom metrics you created in the previous step. You can find more information about exporting metrics in [Cloud Monitoring metric export](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export).
3. Grant project B users or service accounts that you want to have access to the previous metrics exported the following below permissions :

**monitoring.metricDescriptors.get**

**monitoring.metricDescriptors.list**

**monitoring.timeSeries.list**

With the above steps you would have the desired specific metrics in project B available to all the accounts you give the aforementioned permissions to.